# Finding neighbours of an element in a matrix?

Tags: c#, python, algorithm

For example, matrix 3x3

```
'0 1 2
 3 4 5
 6 7 8'
```

for element 0 is 1, 3, 4.

Comment: I can't think over question...

Comment: My English is bad((( Sorry

Comment: Then try [ru.SO].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 2dMatrix: Your matrix
# x: x-coordinate of the element for which you're searching for neighbors 
# y: y-coordinate of the element for which you're searching for neighbors
def nearest_elements_2dMatrix(2dMatrix, x,y):
    upleft = 2dMatrix[x-1][y-1] if (x-1 >= 0 and y-1>=0) else None
    downleft = 2dMatrix[x-1][y+1] if (x-1 >= 0 and y+1 < len(2dMatrix)) else None
    left = 2dMatrix[x-1][y] if x-1 >= 0 else None
    upright = 2dMatrix[x+1][y-1] if (x+1 < len(2dMatrix[0]) and y-1>=0) else None
    right= 2dMatrix[x+1][y] if x+1 < len(2dMatrix[0]) else None
    downright = 2dMatrix[x+1][y+1] if (x+1 < len(2dMatrix[0]) and y+1 < len(2dMatrix)) else None
    above= 2dMatrix[x][y-1] if if y-1 >= 0 else None
    below= 2dMatrix[x][y+1] if if y+1 < len(2dMatrix) else None
    return [upleft, downleft, left, upright, right, downright, above, below]
```

Comment: you forgot the diagonals, and the fact that the input is a value, not coordinates...

Comment: Edited to reflect diagonals, but if the input isn't coordinates this will be impossible if the matrix contains non-unique values